# Ways to run custom windows application in OSx

Tags: windows, macos, virtualization, porting

I would like to know options to run custom windows application (delphi) on MacOS.

I know that the optimal solution would be to re-write the application in objective-c,
but that would take over a year of development.

I know that I could use "bootcamp" or virtual solution.
That includes the expenses of windows + virtual enviroments that is a no-go.

But I wonder if there is a way to actually run windows applications the easy (one click installer) way such as CrossOver or any other similar solutions.

I would be most grateful If you share your ideas!

Comment: As you've discounted using bootcamp and a virtual machine and mentioned CrossOver, Wine is the other option that I can think of, though if you've got the source code, you can also compile other languages for OSX besides Objective-C, so porting may not take as long as you think.

Comment: [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) is worth the price.

Comment: thanks for the opinion. Merlin I have to say i have bad experience with porting J2ME to android. In the end I had to completely re-write the application. Demure I know about Parallels and its pricing. But every customer needs also to include windows, and running a VM just for the sake of one app is unefficient.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done so, after getting feedback from others on other web sites for Beyond Compare, is use Wine. Now I am not certain what all the options are for wine, binary-wise.

I didn't have the time to invest in figuring it out, but someone on twitter, and the beyond compare account itself, recommended Wine Bottler.

http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/

When using wine/wine bottler, the windows apps will see the local file system in a curious way. The real mac local drive appears as "Desktop\My Computer\Z:", and what seems to be a new virtual drive appears as "Desktop\My Computer\C:" with the typical windows folders. Also under desktop: a folder called "/" which is the same as z:

I'm sure someone who has a lot of experience could have answered this question with better elaboration, but these are at least based in my own limited and successful experience.

Comment: Thank you Tom. Currently I am waiting for test app deployment so I can make a complete test. Probably because of file system differences some tweaks in input/output will have to be implemented...